# Generating a random number in Befunge

Tags: random, befunge

I want to generate a random number in Befunge, from 0 to n, where n is an arbitrary number. How would I go about doing this?
I thought of trying this (this example has 2 chained chunks of code to show how it works):

```
v  v
?#>?#>
1  1
+  +
> ^> ^
```

and repeating as needed, but I would need n copies of that chunk of code.
Is there a better way I can generate a random number like `rand(0, 10)` in other languages?

Answer (score 4):

This snippet will mostly do what you want. (It brakes on 0.)

```
0v    \<
>?>\1-:|
 1+    >$
 >^
```

Note that in both my generator and yours the distribution is not flat; it is [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). *This* block will make a random number with a smooth distribution from 0 to 2^n-1:

```
0v  *2\<
>?>\1-:|
 1+    >$
 >^
```

Comment: Thanks! But how should I chain them together?

Answer (score 0):

Shorter versions of [MegaTom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990897/megatom)'s solutions, taking advantage of wrapping:

```
0v     \_$
\?1+\1-:^:-1
```

[TryItOnline!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjB2ICAgICBcXyQuQAogXD8xK1wxLTpeOi0x&input=NA)

and

```
0v   *2\_$
\?1+\1-:^:-1
```

[TryItOnline!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjB2ICAgKjJcXyQuQAogXD8xK1wxLTpeOi0x&input=NA)

Also, here's a very bouncy one-liner for the flat distribution (still wraps vertically at the `?`), because why not! :)

```
1+01->1# +# #?\# 1# -# :#* #2 #\_$
```

[TryItOnline!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjErMDEtPjEjICsjICM_XCMgMSMgLSMgOiMqICMyICNcXyQuQA&input=NA)

Comment: `1+00>+#1 #?\#*1#2-#\:# _$` is 9 bytes shorter

Answer (score 0):

Nerdsniped!

[Here's my solution](https://tio.run/##hc3BCsIwDIDhe58isJ0i1a2ygyFEHyRUGWzixZs97d1rt9UpbOAPKbR8NG3Xv573zp6Otm/bR4yNQ0L4KZiAiESEjbteCrI1MKxjk@DnIk4hwHbeCFGllQoNdHAsqJkGnptZGuOXD8taaQBiIZd0AYuZzi/MGsa/GUR2Isnr9LxfwQmnKfxZtJRxxZjdhJn7vMJSdRsS439ByTG@AQ):

```
  v
  v        >2\ v                        
>>>::0\0\>:|:/2<>*\v      v<<<<<<<         
  ^        >$1\:| :<>:2v  #      ^     @  
  ^             >$ :|:/< >>+>>v  \     .  
                    >   #^?>\$>\:|     -  
                          >^     >$-:0`|
  ^ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< $<
```

Enter on the left, with `n` on the stack. Each `|` marks a new phase of the algorithm.

- In the first phase, we initialize the stack with `n n 0 0 n` and transform that `n` into `2 2 ... 2 2`.
- In the second phase, we multiply up all those 2s to yield `n n 0 0 2^k` for `k >= lg n`.
- In the third phase, we transform `2^k` into `m` = `2^k + 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + ... + 4 + 2 + 1`, except that we use `?` to skip each term with 50% probability.
- In the final phase, we transform `n n m` into (if `n > m`) `m`, and print it; or (if `n <= m`) `n`, and return to the beginning of the entire algorithm.

This generates an unbiased uniform distribution in the half-open range `[0..n)`, for any `n` supplied by the caller.

Here's a test harness that generates and prints `52*:*` = 100 unbiased integers from the half-open range `[0, 10'000)`. [Run it on tio.run.](https://tio.run/##hc3BCsIwDIDhe58isJ0i1a2ygyFEHyRUGWzixZs97d1rt9UpbOAPKbR8NG3Xv573zp6Otm/bR4yNQ0L4KZiAiESEjbteCrI1MKxjk@DnIk4hwHbeCFGllQoNdHAsqJkGnptZGuOXD8taaQBiIZd0AYuZzi/MGsa/GUR2Isnr9LxfwQmnKfxZtJRxxZjdhJn7vMJSdRsS439ByTG@AQ)

```
52*:*            v
v***:::*52_@#:-1 <                   <
v
v        >2\ v                       ^
>::0\0\>:|:/2<>*\v      v<<<<<<<     ^   
^        >$1\:| :<>:2v  #      ^     ^  
^             >$ :|:/< >>+>>v  \     .  
^                 >   #^?>\$>\:|     -  
^                       >^     >$-:0`|
^ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< $<
```